Synthy TV Theme song from the late 70s
I was on YouTube listening to old TV series soundtrack themes and one of them I wanted to listen again but I can't find the video of it, it probably got deleted or something. I have no idea what’s the name of that movie or TV show, in the video there was only the picture of the main character (I think) and then there was the soundtrack theme.
This is what I can remember 
All of these themes were from 70's and 80's including this one. It was a man he looked like he was in his 40's, he had a long curly hair touching his neck length, he had a mustache, and he had dark blue shades on, not sure if it was a policeman but he had similar looks. I also remember that the picture felt like the movie or the series were of action/adventure maybe a bit futuristic but I'm not sure.The background picture of that image (video) was blue and had some background designs etc. The soundtrack itself was like a retro synthwave type of thing, something similar to the soundtrack themes of the TV series 'Streethawk' and 'Airwolf' (more similar to Streethawk) I give you the links so you can have a feel for it. Btw I can also recall that in the video description there was date saying 1978 or 1979 so maybe it’s from those years but don’t take  my word for it.
Streethawk Theme: 


Airwolf Theme: 


I will also give you a picture of the looks that guy had, so you can see what I mean. Non of those pictures are from that video its just so you see what I mean. 



If anyone knows the answer of this TV series or movie, please tell me. Then I will see if it’s the same theme that I'm looking for.
P.S If none of you know, maybe you could give me a good website that shows you all TV shows and Movies that were ever released in a specific year so I can look for it myself. It's very important for me!

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

You wrote "I can't find the video", which sounds like you might have been searching for it on YouTube.  Instead of that, check your YouTube "History". It will show you all the videos you've watched. Maybe you will recognize the video's thumbnail or title.

Well yes but I forgot to mention I had to install new windows and it got wiped out so pretty much it's lost and don't mention the bookmarks because I haven't bookmark it. I had a a few unimportant bookmarks its not a loss to me. Shame though because if I knew it would get deleted I would write the title or download it somehow, it's just that I didn't know.

You can search through Wiki year-by-year--for example, 1978: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1978_in_American_television

Could it be Automan? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kA1NT4I0s34

also, maybe you can find it in this video?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_87i7FhkIs

No it's not Automan unfortunately. Yes searching through wikipedia I night find it I know but the thing is, it's so damn long, I will wait abit until someone will give their answers, you never know maybe it will be the right one.
